# Xtext add elements to parent feature

Tags: xtext

I want to implement a domain specific language using Xtext, and I'm having some trouble with keeping things clean and reusable. Consider the following example:

```
Spec:
    'spec' '(' attrs=AttrAsgnList? ')';
AttrAsgnList:
    attrs+=AttrAsgn (',' attrs+=AttrAsgn)*;
AttrAsgn:
    name=ID '=' value=INT;
```

Working with this in Xtend, one would now access the single attributes like this (given a Spec object):

```
for (a : spec.attrs.attrs) ...
```

I would much prefer it if I didn't have to go through two levels every time I want to access attributes. The obvious way to prevent this is to inline the whole *AttrAsgnList* rule into *Spec*, so that the *attrs* feature of *Spec* becomes a list. However, I will need to use constructs like this quite a lot in my DSL, and imo it is bad style to just copy it over and over again.

I am basically looking for a way to directly feed the single *AttrAsgn* elements into the parent *attrs* feature. Is that possible or am I stuck with either living with the indirection or bloating everything up by inlining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you case that should be no problem

```
Spec:
'spec' '(' (attrs+=AttrAsgn (',' attrs+=AttrAsgn)*)? ')';
```

And no there is no direct way to prevent this copy and pasting

The only chance would be a m2m through `IDerivedStateComputer` but that would mean you would have elements twice so you would have to clutter the grammar and the metamodel anyway http://xtextcasts.org/episodes/18-model-optimization